# How to limit all input values sum to specific number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

```
useEffect(() => {
    const count = watchAllInputs.reduce((acc: number, current: { productPiece: any; }): any => {
        return acc + Number(current.productPiece)

    }, 0);

    setPieceCount(count)

}, [watchRowInputs.productPiece])




const handleAmountOnChange = (value: any) => {

    const amount = data[0].amount

    console.log(value.target.value)
    
    let inputValue = Number(value.target.value);

    if (inputValue > amount - pieceCount) {
      inputValue = amount - pieceCount;
    }
  
    setValue(`requirement.${index}.productPiece`, inputValue);

}
```

Hi all. I try to limit all input fields sum value to 6. And `pieceCount` variable is sum of inputs values. Actually it works for example when i try to enter input 9 value it change to 6 but for another example if try to enter 4 value it change to input value to 4 because 4 lower than 6 and now my `pieceCount` is 4. But then if i enter 3 value to input it change to input value to 2 because `amount`(6) - `piecentCount`(4) equals 2. But i want to change input value to 3. How can i fix that ?

Comment: you can use HTML max min properties: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me: You want `piecentCount` to be max. `6`, but you want `inputValue` be 3, if `piecentCount` is `4` ? So you want `6 - 4` to be `3` ? I suggest to add more relevant code. What is `amount` ? What is `data[0]` ?